# Как запустить скрипт на выходе из другого?

Tags: python-3.x

Доброго времени суток! Как запустить внешний скрипт при завершении основного? Например, нужно отредактировать основной скрипт, для этого генерируется новый скрипт, который откроет основной как текстовый файл и запишет изменения. Как запустить этот вновь созданный скрипт из основного?
Заранее благодарен

Comment: На каком языке написан скрипт, который модифицирует исходный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если внешний скрипт уже импортирован, можете сделать

```
 imp.reload(spam)
```

Если нет, написать import

Comment: А он выполнит при этом секцию в `if __name__ == '__main__':`?

Comment: Не должен. Это только при самостоятельном запуске

Comment: А как нужно, чтобы выполнялось или нет?

Comment: Так топикстартера спросите ;)

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka не нужно